# KeyCloak bulk update through PSQL db

Tags: postgresql, keycloak, rancher, keycloak-gatekeeper

I've updated all my users to email_verified = true. The PSQL database gets updated, but the admin console continues to have the users as not having their emails verified. I'm doing the changes through the CLI on Rancher.

The command I am using is:

```sql
UPDATE user_entity SET email_verified = true WHERE email_verified = false
```

The only help I was able to see on here was from [Bulk update of users in KeyCloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34840830/bulk-update-of-users-in-keycloak).

Is there more complexity to updating users in bulk?
Is there other ways to mass updating users?

Comment: Have you restarted Keycloak (or cleared caches) after the change?

Comment: Yes, our Keycloak automatically restarts every hour.

Comment: I just tested your query on Keycloak 8.0.1. It works fine and I see e-mail verified true on UI immediately. Another guess - have you committed your update?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the old data is still around in Keycloak's cache. Some options are:

1. Restart Keycloak
2. Clear the cache
3. Turn off caching permanently

For #2, you can clear the user or realm caches at runtime on the "Realm Settings -> Cache" section of the keycloak admin page:

[image]

For #3, you can read the below source for instructions: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_single_sign-on/7.0/html/server_installation_and_configuration_guide/server_cache_configuration

> 8.3. Disabling Caching

> To disable the realm or user cache, you must edit the keycloak-server.json file in your distribution. Where this file lives depends on your operating mode Here’s what the config looks like initially.

```
"userCache": {
    "default" : {
        "enabled": true
    }
},

"realmCache": {
    "default" : {
        "enabled": true
    }
},
```

> To disable the cache set the enabled field to false for the cache you want to disable. You must reboot your server for this change to take effect.

> 8.4. Clearing Caches at Runtime

> To clear the realm or user cache, go to the Red Hat Single Sign-On admin console Realm Settings→Cache Config page. On this page you can clear the realm cache or the user cache. This will clear the caches for all realms and not only the selected realm.